# Inspect ReaderQuotas settings via OperationContext

Tags: wcf, operationcontext

I have a WCF service for which I have specified custom binding/readerQuotas settings. However, the service still fails with the message:

> The maximum string content length quota (...) has been exceeded"

I suspect that the readerQuotas settings may not get applied, because the service is instantiated via a custom `ServiceHostFactory` (to which I don't have access).

Is there a way to inspect the current readerQuotas settings for a service using the `OperationContext`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found a quick an dirty way to do  this:

```
((WSHttpBinding)OperationContext.Current.Host.Description.Endpoints[0].Binding).ReaderQuotas
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if the host supports multiple endpoints, usually when multiple bindings are offered, you're likely getting the wrong binding.